# Can't Install App with WatchKit Extension on iOS 8.1 Simulator with Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, simulator, watchkit

I have an app with an iOS Deployment Target of iOS 7.0, and I've added a WatchKit target. As expected, the `WatchKit` Extension has an iOS Deployment Target of 8.2. When I run the primary app on the iOS 8.2 simulator, everything works as-expected. However, if I try to run it on the iOS 8.1 simulator, Xcode reports: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)`

**The CoreSimulator.log file contains the following message:**

> com.apple.dt.Xcode[12181] : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7ff46e2dc980 {Error=AppexBundleUnknownExtensionPointIdentifier, ErrorDescription=Appex bundle at /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xmo2ks/extracted/InstallBug.app/PlugIns/InstallBug WatchKit Extension.appex with id com..InstallBug.watchkitextension specifies a value (com.apple.watchkit) for the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in the NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist that does not correspond to a known extension point.

I don't see any mention of this issue in the release notes, and I'm wondering if this is something that others have encountered. If so, is there something else that I need to configure to make this work? If not, I'll file a bug report.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Xcode 6.2.

You can workaround it by adding a `"MinimumOSVersion" = "8.2"` key-value pair to your Apple Watch extensions's Info.plist file.

Comment: (I had to enter it using the right click -> show raw keys / values option, but : ) This solved my problem. How did you know it? Why isn't the selectable "LSMinimumSystemVersion" is the one which solves this issue? Thanks!

Comment: worked for me too but don't understand why. Another project I have did not require this. Can it be that the current project which required `"MinimumOSVersion" = "8.2"` was created with an older version of Xcode? @dan

Answer (score 1):

Users will have to be updated to iOS 8.2 in order to install and run a Watch App. Anyone not running iOS 8.2+ will not be prompted to install the Watch App and won't even know that it is available. There are several reasons for this.

- The Apple Watch iOS App isn't available on iOS until iOS 8.2+
- The Watch Extension APIs for an iOS app weren't available until iOS 8.2+

There is some additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095351/watchkit-apps-extensions-and-ios-backwards-compatibility).

Hopefully that helps shed some light.