# Unable to install app on watchOS simulator Xcode9, iOS11, watchOS4 app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, xcode9, watchos-2

I wrote a program for watchOS and tried running it on simulator. I am unable to run this app on simulator, installation fails with error: Unable to install the app.

I am using xcode9, Simulator: iphone7 + Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm
Here is my CoreSimulator.log summary

> Nov 17 10:38:47 xyz-iMac com.apple.dt.Xcode[351] :
>   installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error
>   Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=2 "This app was unable to be
>   installed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app was unable to be
>   installed., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbc74153480 {Error
>   Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=59 "Appex bundle at
>   /Users/fe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/58D7256F-1247-48E3-BDE2-F2F44CEEB0E9/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Sku79o/extracted/testwatch.app/Watch/testwatch
>   WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/testwatch WatchKit Extension.appex with id
>   com.test.testwatch.watchkitapp.watchkitextension specifies a value
>   (com.apple.watchkit) for the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in the
>   NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist that does not correspond to a
>   known extension point."
>   UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=AppexBundleUnknownExtensionPointIdentifier,
>   FunctionName=-[MIPluginKitPluginBundle overlaidInfoPlistWithError:],
>   SourceFileLine=215, NSLocalizedDescription=Appex bundle at
>   /Users/fe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/58D7256F-1247-48E3-BDE2-F2F44CEEB0E9/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Sku79o/extracted/testwatch.app/Watch/testwatch
>   WatchKit App.app/PlugIns/testwatch WatchKit Extension.appex with id
>   com.test.testwatch.watchkitapp.watchkitextension specifies a value
>   (com.apple.watchkit) for the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in the
>   NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist that does not correspond to a
>   known extension point.}}}

[This is the error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1MIX.png)
[This is info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilMZt.png)

Comment: [NSExtensionPointIdentifier: This key is required for every app extension, and must be placed as an immediate child of the NSExtension key.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW15) Can you post your Info.plist?

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order between

> NSExtensionPointIdentifier

and

> NSExtensionAttributes

[NSExtensionPointIdentifier: This key is required for every app extension, and must be placed as an immediate child of the NSExtension key.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW15)

This key is supported in iOS 8 and later and in macOS 10.10 and later.
Check IOS version.

[Have you tried taking a look at this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100257/cant-install-app-with-watchkit-extension-on-ios-8-1-simulator-with-xcode-6-2)

Comment: I have not changed any settings. This is what Xcode has provided.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I am using MacOS 10.13.1, Xcode 9.1
and Simulator iOS 11.1

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Xcode resolved this issue.